# What is the formula to convert a color in CMYK to hex?

Tags: colors, hex, cmyk

What is the formula for converting a color encoded in CMYK to its hexadecimal equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have bad news for you: there is no simple formula. Cyan, magenta and yellow are complex ink colours and the translation to RGB depends on [colour profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_profile). To make things worse, the CMYK colour space is smaller than the RGB colour space. Some pointers on colour theory:

- [handprint: do "primary" colors exist?](http://www.handprint.com/HP/WCL/color6.html)
- [Plotting colors properly on a computer screen](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/colour/rainbow.html)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with javascript:

```js
//converts cmyk to hex
function cmykToHex(c,m,y,k) {
    var hex,
        rgb;
    //convert cmyk to rgb first
    rgb = cmykToRgb(c,m,y,k);
    //then convert rgb to hex
    hex = rgbToHex(rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
    //return hex color format
    return hex;
}
//converts cmyk color to rgb
function cmykToRgb(c, m, y, k) {
var rgb_r,
    rgb_g,
    rgb_b,
    cyan = 100 *Number(c),
    magenta = 100 * Number(m),
    yellow = 100 * Number(y),
    black = 100 * Number(k); // fixed a typo
    0 < cyan ? cyan /= 100 : 0 < magenta ? magenta /= 100 : 0 < yellow ? yellow /= 100 : 0 < black && (black /= 100);
    rgb_r = 1 - Math.min(1, cyan * (1 - black) + black);
    rgb_g = 1 - Math.min(1, magenta * (1 - black) + black);
    rgb_b = 1 - Math.min(1, yellow * (1 - black) + black);
    rgb_r = Math.round(255 * rgb_r);
    rgb_g = Math.round(255 * rgb_g);
    rgb_b = Math.round(255 * rgb_b);
    return {r: rgb_r, g: rgb_g, b: rgb_b};
}
//converts rgb to hex
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
    function componentToHex(c) {
        var hex = c.toString(16);
        return hex.length === 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    }
}
```