# How to convert a color code formatted as 0.986246,0.007121,0.027434,1.000000

Tags: colors

I need to convert a bunch of color codes to Hex. The codes are in this format:

0.986246,0.007121,0.027434,1.000000

Has anyone seen this format before and know a way to convert to Hex?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? I suspect you just need to map [0, 1] to [0x0, 0xff] but it's pretty hard to answer without seeing a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual**

CMYK encode:
https://convertingcolors.com/cmy-color-0.9862_0.0071_0.0274.html?search=CMY(0.986246,0.007121,0.027434)

this is a decoder, the last one 1.0 is the alpha or transparency

[image: screenshot of the URL sent]

**Script**

If you are handy on Javascript there is a script to convert: [What is the formula to convert a color in CMYK to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325469/what-is-the-formula-to-convert-a-color-in-cmyk-to-hex)